# How to send foreignkey data type in API by DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have API written by Django Rest Framework:

models.py

```
STATUSES = (("F", "free"),
            ("R", "registered"),
            ("N", "not free")
            )
class Collector(models.Model):
    ip = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Коллектор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Коллекторы'
        ordering = ('ip',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ip)


class Port(models.Model):
    port = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUSES, default="F")
    collector_link = models.ForeignKey(Collector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Порт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Порты'
        ordering = ('port',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.port)
```

serializers.py

```
class CollectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Collector
        fields = ("__all__")

class PortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Port
        fields = ("__all__")
```

views.py

```
class CollectorAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CollectorSerializer
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ip = request.POST['ip']
        obj = models.Collector(ip=request.POST['ip'])
        obj.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class PortAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PortSerializer
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        port, status1, collector_link = request.POST["port"], request.POST["status"], request.POST["collector_link"]
        entry = models.Port(port=port, status=status1, collector_link=collector_link)
```

entry.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
In result, when I'm trying to send data to API in json format like `{"port": "1", "status": "F", "collector_link": "10"}` (collector_link=10 is id of collector instance in data base) I'm getting the next error:

> ValueError at /sm/api/v1/port/ Cannot assign "'10'":
>   "Port.collector_link" must be a "Collector" instance
>   How I can to fix it?
>   .

Comment: You're reimplementing most everything that `CreateApiView` does for free. Try reading up on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using django rest framework's serializer class, but you don't have apply it in your views, also you are doing `request.POST` which is not convenient, rather you should use `request.data`. So update your `PortAPIView` as follows,

```
class PortAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PortSerializer
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **collector_link_id** key instead on **collector_link**

```
entry = models.Port(port=port, status=status1, collector_link_id=int(collector_link))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your view to

```
class PortAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PortSerializer
    allowed_methods = ["POST"]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return response.Ok(serializer.data)
```

And you serializer to

```
class PortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Port
        fields = ("__all__")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        collector = Collector.objects.create(ip=validated_data["collector"])
        port = Port.objects.create(port=validated_data["port"], status=validated_data["status"], collector_link=collector)
        return port
```

This should resolve your query. I hope it helps! :)